# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not allowing HTTP GET from a remote server

Tags: ajax, url-rewriting, cors, same-origin-policy

I'm using Ajax to download XML using HTTP GET getting following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://remoteserverfqdn:8444/cuic/permalink/PermalinkViewer.htmx?viewId=F52A08751000014B3835F5E80AB43E68&linkType=xmlType&viewType=Grid. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

The code I'm using to get data:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://remoteserverfqdn:8444/cuic/permalink/PermalinkViewer.htmx?viewId=F52A08751000014B3835F5E80AB43E68&linkType=xmlType&viewType=Grid",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
});
```

Remote server is a blackbox so there's nothing I can do on that side to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I tried installing ARR and URL Rewrite on IIS to act as a reverse proxy. That works fine when accessing the page directly in a browser, but when using Ajax and HTTP GET it gives me the same error.

Does anyone know a different method I could use to download the xml bypassing CORS? I did read up on JSONP but I think a change on the server side (the blackbox one) is needed for that to work?

If ARR and URL rewrite is the correct way to go for this, does anyone know if there is a setting available there I'm missing to set the Origin HTTP header to the remote server url.

Comment: Have you tried `contentType: text/plain` and/or `headers: {'X-Requested-With:','XMLHttpRequest'}`?

Comment: Tried both just now, same result. Not sure if I added the headers part correctly though, only way for me to add it without getting an error was:headers: "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",

Comment: Exactly as was in my comment, text/plain  be quoted

Comment: I did find a way around this problem. The blackbox actually provides a method that can be used instead of ajax that is not affected by CORS. The method is called gadgets.io.makeRequest.